# XML parsing Android

Tags: java, android

I am using JDOM to create XML and during parsing i am getting this exception 
"Could not find class 'java.rmi.RemoteException', referenced from method org.jdom.JDOMException.getNestedException
"  which cause a crash in program .This exception occurs  very frequently but not always 
Any body has faced same problem .
Any help would be appreciated
Thanks in advance.

Comment: SAXBuilder builder  = new SAXBuilder();
       Document doc   = null;
       try {
        doc = builder.build(new StringReader(xmlData));
               }catch(Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
       }


getting exception at build.build

Comment: There are three XML parsers already on Android: DOM, SAX, and XmlPullParser. Why do you need a fourth?

Answer (score 2):

Well there is no RMI implementation in android platform, so it pretty obviously the reason of the exception. Don't know why JDOM needs `java.rmi.RemoteException` through

**Edit:**
There is a code inside of `JDOMException` which checks  `instanceof` expression against `java.rmi.RemoteException` so this is the root of problem.