# Get values from a XML contained in a String

Tags: android, xml

I have a String variable containing an XML:

```
String xml = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?><CourtactSioux><ListeContact><IdContactClient>212</IdContactClient><DateContact>25/06/2012 08:09</DateContact><TypeForm>STANDARD</TypeForm><Foyer>2</Foyer><Civilite>M</Civilite><Nom>TEST</Nom><Prenom>JULIEN</Prenom><NomJeuneFille></NomJeuneFille></ListeContact></CourtactSioux>"
```

And I want to take values from this XML, how to do ?
For exemple: get "Civilite" value.

### I tried this:

```
                String xml = cn.getXml();
                Integer demandeId = cn.getID();

                XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
                Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

                NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

// looping through all item nodes <item>
                for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                    idApplication = parser.getValue(e, IdApplication);
                    idContactClient = parser.getValue(e, IdContactClient);
                    logement = parser.getValue(e, Logement);
                    typeForm = parser.getValue(e, TypeForm);
                }

                id = idApplication + idContactClient;

                    Product product =  new Product()
                            .setId(id)
                            .setName(logement)
                            .setCategory(typeForm)
                            .setPrice(1)
                            .setQuantity(1);
                    ProductAction productAction = new ProductAction(ProductAction.ACTION_PURCHASE)
                            .setTransactionId(id)
                            .setTransactionAffiliation("Solutis")
                            .setTransactionRevenue(1);
                    HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder builder = new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder()
                            .addProduct(product)
                            .setProductAction(productAction);

                    Tracker t = ((App) getApplication()).getTracker();
                    t.setScreenName("transaction");
                    t.send(builder.build());
                }
```

It's work, get attention on the aprent node of your xml

Comment: use xml parsing : http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: use [XML Parser](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_xml_parsers.htm) for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse XML on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420835/parse-xml-on-android)

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML parsing Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873497/xml-parsing-android)

Comment: @bpA Look my edit please

Comment: @UmairM Look my edit please

Comment: @AnirudhSharma Look what I tryed to do please

Comment: @RamBabuPudari Look my edit please

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of parsing XML in android. You could use [XMLReader.parse(InputSource)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xml/sax/XMLReader.html#parse(org.xml.sax.InputSource)) by wrapping the string in a reader, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280761/how-do-i-create-an-org-xml-sax-inputsource-from-a-string)

Check the [Parsing XML Data](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html#instantiate) part of Android Developers site for more information.